# How to deploy AngularJS static app Rails 5 api full separate on same droplet?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, nginx, deployment, digital-ocean

I have a Rails 5 API fully separate with capistrano. I have a ubuntu droplet on Digital Ocean and its running Rails 5 API deployed with capistrano, nginx, passenger phussion, postgresql.

I have a separate Angular front static website which will be dropped in AWS s3. Due to latency issue and pricing, I want both app front and back end on same droplet. Is it possible? If yes how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a second server block on nginx to your Angular project.
Copy and edit the default configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`,

```
sudo cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/angular_project
```

Point it to the folder containing your front end and set your domain name:

```
server {
    ...
    root angular/project/path;
    server_name frontend.domain.name.com; 
    ...
}
```

Then enable the server block:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/angular_project /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

And restart the ngingx service

```
sudo service nginx restart
```